# Задать размер нового окна через window.open

Tags: javascript

Задаю размер окна двумя способами:

**первый**

```
box_window = window.open(self.options.form_url, '_blank', 'База знаний', 'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,top=50,left=50,width=400,height=400');
```

**второй**

```
box_window = window.open(self.options.form_url, '_blank', 'База знаний', 'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,top=50,left=50,width='+screen.availWidth+',height='+screen.availHeight+'');
```

Во всех случаях в хроме 25 версии окно открывается в маленьком размере (100х100).

Какие еще есть способы задать размер окна?

**UPD**

Мой вопрос заключается именно в **размере нового окна**. То есть как его заставить работать в старой версии хром. А так окно корректно открывается во всех остальных версиях всех браузеров.

Comment: Ну не знаю как оно может работать для всех остальных версий браузеров если параметры не на своих местах  https://jsfiddle.net/4fb56s85/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если смотреть [документацию по методу](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp), то увидим, что дополнительные опции окна передаются третьим параметром для window.open, а не четвертым.

```
var myAwesomeWindow = window.open('', '', 'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,top=50,left=50,width=400,height=400');
myAwesomeWindow.document.title = 'myAwesomeTitle';
```

Comment: чем ваш код отличается от  моего первого варианта?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova наверное тем, что третий параметр, для window.open, не четвертый. %)

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, внимательно перечитайте строчку номер два моего ответа пжлста) Можно несколько раз, пока не придет понимание.

Comment: @Утка теперь это монолит %)